# How post login form data in YII2

Tags: ajax, url, post, yii2

Login page is on index when i click on login menu then popup display when i fill up all then post all data in site controller after success redirect to customer panel,But i am getting error in ajax code url,How resolved this problem? 
$("#login").submit(function () {

```
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo Url::toRoute(["site/customerloged"]);  ?>",                                       
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data == 1){
                    window.location.href = 'customer/home';                                      
                    return false;
                }else{
                    alert(data);                                                      
                    return false;
                }                      
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Show the error messge please..

Comment: I change the url  url: 'site/customerloged', this url working fine on localhost but not working on live server "Unable to verify your data submission." error display

Comment: Do you have CSRF enabled?